# Unity 3D Move object over specific time on GetButtonDown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got an empty game object filled with all my player components, within it is a model which animates itself when the controls are pressed which are instantiated by GetButtonDown. Currently everything in the player game object moves instantly to the next point (basically teleports there with no transition). Is there a way I can get it all to move over say 1 second rather than going there instantly? Here's what happens on GetButtonDown

```
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("VerticalFwd"))
    {

        amountToMove.y = 1f;
        transform.Translate (amountToMove);
    }
```

I've tried transform.Translate (amountToMove * Time.deltaTime * randomint);
and all sorts of ways to use Time
however that doesn't seem to work even though it seems the most logical way. I'm guessing because the GetButtonDown only "runs" when it is pressed and has no update function to "time" the move every frame? Any ideas?
amountToMove is saved as a Vector3 aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try .Lerp, it runs as a coroutine interpolating a value over some amount of time    *Vector3.Lerp(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, float time)*

See documentation [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)

This should give you a rough idea of whats going on

```
Vector3 Distance = End - Start; 
// this will return the difference 

this.transform.position += Distance/time.deltatime * Movetime 
// this divides the Distance equal to the time.deltatime.. (Use Movetime to make the movement take more or less then 1 second
```

IE: If the Distance is 1x.1y.1z, and time.deltatime is .1 and Movetime is 1.... you get a movement of .1xyz per tick, taking 1 second to reach the end point

*FYI: transform.Translate works as a fancy .position +=, for this purpose you can use them interchangeably*

**EDIT** 
Here are a few solutions

Easy ::

```
Vector3 amountToMove = new Vector3(0,1,0); //  Vector3.up is short hand for (0,1,0) if you want to use that instead

if (Input.GetButtonDown ("VerticalFwd"))
    {

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position ,transform.position + amountToMove, 1);
    }
```

Hard and probably unnecessary  ::

Write a Coroutine that does a kind of Linear interpolation for your specific application [See documentation here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Coroutines.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm getting confused as to how to declare my start and end positions? Currently I've got a Vector3 amountToMove and I simple +1 to one of the axis and translate that into a transformation. How would I do this with transform.position, I know I would need a variable Transform to get the objects current position and another one as the end position but how would I +1 on an axis in the end Transform? Unless I'm being a blind stupid idiot the Unity reference doesn't clear it up :/

Comment: Try *transform.position* for start : and *transform.position* + *amountToMove* for the end? .... Or am I failing to understand the problem

Comment: I'm literally completely lost now, I can't believe I'm being so stupid that I can't get this to work...thanks for your help anyway :/

Comment: *<Violating Stack overflows terms and conditions>* Email me at Dmaydrum@gmail.com and I will help you with understanding Unity's transform system *</Violating Stack overflows terms and conditions>*

Answer (score 1):

The first formula is wrong. The correct formula would be:

```
this.transform.position += (Distance/MoveTime) * time.deltatime
```